# Computing the fixed point for $\cos x$

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

While studying about Compiler Design I came with the term 'fixed point'.I looked in wikipedia and got the definition of fixed point but couldn't get how fixed point is computed for $\cos x$ as said in [fixed point](http://1drv.ms/1ETRRk1).

It says that the fixed point for $\cos x=x$ using Intermediate Value Theorem.But I couldn't get how they computed the fixed point for $\cos x$.Do anyone know how they computed this?

Comment: The fixed point for $\cos(x)$ is exactly the value $x_0$for which $\cos(x_0)=x_0$. That's is precisely the same task, as stated by @Lolman, of finding the zeroes of the function $f(x):=\cos(x)-x$

Comment: Don't you just mean calculating the zeroes of $\cos(x)-x$?

Comment: @Lolman:that's what I meant.

Comment: @Lolman:I think that there should be a value where $cosx$ and x should be equal.Do you know any value at which $cosx$ and x would be equal?

Comment: @justin 0.73908513321516064166...

Comment: @Lolman:that's right.

Comment: More digits  0.73908513321516064165531208767387340401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an equation as:

$$x = \cos x$$

We can write this as an iteration formula:

$$x_{n+1} = \cos x_n$$

We would choose a starting value and iterate it:

- $x_0 = 0.75$
- $x_1 = \cos x_0 = \cos(0.75) = 0.731689$
- $x_2 = \cos x_1 = \cos(0.731689) = 0.744047$
- $\ldots$
- We arrive at a repeating sequence with $x = 0.739085$.
- We would of course do this to whatever precision we needed (if the fixed point exists).

**Check**

Claim is that $x = \cos x$:

$$\cos(0.739085) = 0.739085$$

You can see more details in these [*notes*](http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture9.pdf) that include this very example to high precision.